# Should 'First Lady' be capped in all references?

Tags: punctuation

Should *First Lady* be capped in all references?

•I spoke with the *First Lady*, Michelle Obama.
•Do you want to speak with the *First Lady*?
•Former *First Lady* Barbara Bush attended the ceremony.

And what about *the First Couple* and *the First Kids*?

•The *First Couple* [Barack and Michelle] arrived in Washington.

•The *First Kids* [Barack and Michelle's kids] arrived with their parents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should ‘Ground Zero’ (site of old World Trade Center) be capped in all references?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154098/should-ground-zero-site-of-old-world-trade-center-be-capped-in-all-reference) (they're both "proper nouns" so they're both *capitalised*)

Comment: No, not always. See the definition(s) in a good dictionary.

Comment: Good luck looking up "First Couple" and "First Kids" in a dictionary. Even with "First Lady", I'm not sure it's always capitalized; certainly, in historical usage it wasn't always.

Answer (score 1):

If you use it like a title, capitalize it.  If you don't like that, don't use it at all!  *First Kids.*  Good Lord.

Comment: And, if you don't use it as a title, don't!  The first lady off the boat doesn't get any special honors!  And, I agree *First Kids* is a bridge too far!