# Should ‘Ground Zero’ (site of old World Trade Center) be capped in all references?

Tags: punctuation

Should *Ground Zero* (site of old World Trade Center) be capitalised in all references?

Comment: It's a proper noun, so yes.

Answer (score 3):

In this usage, yes.  The site has semi-officially come to be known as Ground Zero.  Much like you would capitalize the semi-official name of a neighborhood (*e.g* Tribeca), you would capitalize this name.

As FumbleFingers points out, the name is now a proper noun, and gets capitalized.

If describing the point of a bomb's impact, however, you would not capitalize ground zero.  [See the Wikipedia article on ground zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_zero) vs. the [Wikipedia article on the World Trade Center site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Trade_Center_site) for the two usages in juxtaposition.

Answer (score 0):

Only when it is used in the exclusive sense of 'site of old World Trade Center', not otherwise.

Comment: If I name a bar Ground Zero, it becomes a proper noun and gets capitalized.  If I name a dog Ground Zero it becomes a proper noun and gets capitalized.  And so on.  It is not exclusive to the site of the World Trade Center.

Comment: @DavidM I meant exactly that. The 'site of old W...' is only an example here.